# Configure Postgres auto-increment sequence starting value for all sequences in one place

Tags: postgresql

In a special use case, I want to configure postgres auto-increment sequences to start from 100001  instead of 1 across whole DB for all the tables. Could it be configured in one place for the tables instead of altering all the sequences after table setup?

Comment: You will have to do that when creating the tables e.g. `id integer generated always as identity (start with 100001)`

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, yeah, that would be the way to go if there is no other way.